# Android Studio min sdk 22 no es posible

Tags: android

Acabo de descargar el android studio pero el sdk no me permite colocar el min sdk a 22 , me obliga a colocar el 23 según la librería *wear-26.1.0*

Mi smartwatch tiene android 5.1 api 22 y necesito poder crear la app con minsdk 22.

El error es el siguiente

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 22 cannot be smaller
>   than version 23 declared in library [com.android.support:wear:26.1.0]
>   C:\Users\Pet.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\wear-26.1.0.aar\01466bada77ea7c4693dc210da48fb22\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 22

Ya he descargado la el sdk 22 desde el sdk manager pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error, ya hice cleam y rebuild y nada.

Leí en un foro que ya no es posible colocar el minsdk menor a 23 por la nueva actualización de google pero esto no lo creo.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Te esta diciendo que no puedes usar api 22 con la libreria com.android.support:wear:26.1.0 porque su minima es 23. Si quieres usar api 22 tendras que poner una version inferior de wear.

Comment: Y donde me descargo una versión inferior?

Answer (score 2):

Como comentas, en realidad la librería tiene definido como `minSdkVersion 23`, ya que **actualmente no existe soporte de [Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library) para la API 22** (Junio 2018) que es la que tiene definida como mínimo tu proyecto, por esta razón te sugiere usarlo.

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 22 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared
>   in library

Puedes buscar una versión de [Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library) anterior a la `26.0.x` aunque no lo considero recomendable.

Como solución te sugiero actualizar tu dispositivo, muy probablemente tiene actualización Android 6.0

Comment: Tengo el amazfit pace y no me deja actualizar mas allá del android 5.1

Comment: @Minniek ups! si es la primera versión me parece tiene 4.x ?